# Inconsistency between doc and pdf after convertin word to Pdf in Aspose

Tags: java, aspose, aspose.words, aspose.pdf

I have a pdf file:

https://uploadfiles.io/uki01

that converted to word by Aspose.pdf and output is :

https://ufile.io/ikwgx
why after convert from pdf to word , the text of word is out of area and And the texts are in a group format.

how can I edit this code to achieve my goal?

my code is :

```
Document document = new Document("x"+".pdf");
document.save("x" + ".docx", SaveFormat.DocX);
```

Answer (score 0):

for text grouping problem,I test this code and my problem solved:

```
DocSaveOptions saveOptions = new DocSaveOptions();
saveOptions.setMode(DocSaveOptions.RecognitionMode.Flow);
saveOptions.setFormat(DocSaveOptions.DocFormat.DocX);
document.save(Constants.EXP_DIR + token + ".docx", saveOptions);
```

but for text out of table issue ,I still have a problem.

Comment: I am developer evangelist at Aspose and I have observed the issue regarding text out of table. It has been logged in our issue tracking system under the ticket ID PDFJAVA-36953. We will further investigate the issue and keep you updated as soon as we have some new on it. Please spare us little time. We are sorry for the inconvenience.